# Navbar Links Extensions Bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4

I have nested a "navbar" in Bootstrap row. The problem which I've got is how to make links "extend" to the whole column.

[image]

Code for that looks like this:

```
            <div class="col-6 p-3">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="justify-content: space-between;">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav w-100">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-black" href="#">Link1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-black" href="#">Link2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-black" href="#">Link3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-black" href="#">Link4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-black" href="#">Link5</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

(w-100 class doesn't work)

On the Bootstrap page [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navbar/] unfortunately I do not see a example like this. And on "navs" there is an example with the class "nav-fill" [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navs/#fill-and-justify]. It doesn't work either.

Is it possible to stretch the nav-links so that they take up all the space at equal intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make Navbar Links "extend" to the whole column,try to add class `col` to `<li></li>`.

```
<div class="col-6 p-3">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="justify-content: space-between;">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav w-100">
                    <li class="nav-item col">
                        <a class="nav-link text-black" href="#">Link1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item col">
                        <a class="nav-link text-black" href="#">Link2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item col">
                        <a class="nav-link text-black" href="#">Link3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item col">
                        <a class="nav-link text-black" href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item col">
                        <a class="nav-link text-black" href="#">Link5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

result:

[image]